# Получаю сообщение invalid function name ..myjino.ru/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

загрузил Вордпресс на мой новый аккаунт на хостинге Джино. Получаю следующее сообщение - см ниже. Кстати, по совету поддержки Джино, поменял везде версию php с 7.1 на 7.4. Не изменилось ничего, по прежнему наверху каждой открывающейся страницы сайта получаю

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'head_hook' not found or invalid function name in /home/users/v/vadimidasilva/domains/vadimidasilva.myjino.ru/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287

что это может быть и главное, как это убрать?

Comment: с версии 7.1 идут новые обработчики ошибок... попробуй уж 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Это ошибка в теме, попробуйте поискать ответ [тут](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/fix-outdated-templates-woocommerce/)

Answer (score 0):

проблема в том, что где-то в теме у Вас идет привязка хука к несуществующей функции 'head_hook'

попробуйте поискать в теме привязку к хуку вида и удалить эти привязки либо создать функцию  'head_hook'

```
add_action( 'hook_name', 'head_hook' );
```

где hook_name - может быть какой-то хук вордпресс